# Get weekdays as column based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this code to get the following output:

```
idx = pd.date_range("2021-06-08", periods=3, freq="D")
ts = pd.Series(['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'], index=idx)
ts

2021-06-08      Tuesday
2021-06-09    Wednesday
2021-06-10     Thursday
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

But I don't want to pass list of days. I want that this should extract weekday from index only. I tried following code to get this but this is giving me error:

```
idx = pd.date_range("2021-06-08", periods=3, freq="D")
ts = pd.Series((x for x in idx.weekday()), index=idx)
```

Do anyone have any idea of how to get this and suggest what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day_name.html):

```
idx = pd.date_range("2021-06-08", periods=3, freq="D")
ts = pd.Series(idx.day_name(), index=idx)
print (ts)
2021-06-08      Tuesday
2021-06-09    Wednesday
2021-06-10     Thursday
Freq: D, dtype: object
```